# If $M$ is a manifold and $f:M\rightarrow R$ is continous then $\int_M f dV$ can be evaluated breaking $M$ up into some pieces.

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds

At the 25-th chapter of the text *Analysis on Manifold* James Munkres defines the integration of a scalar continuous function over a manifold but he states that the definition he gave (see [here](http://libgen.rs/search.php?req=+Munkres+Analysis+on+Manifolds&open=0&res=25&view=simple&phrase=1&column=def) for details if you don't know the definition of a scalar continuous function over a manifold) is only *satisfactory for theoretical purposes* so that he proves the following formula to obtain a more convenient way to calculate that integral. So I want discuss some passages of the step $1$ of the following theorem that I did not understood completely.

[image]

So I don't understand why it is sufficient to prove the last theorem in the case where the support of the function $f$ is contained in a single coordinate patch, why for each $i=1,...,N$ the set $W_i$ is open in $\Bbb R^k$ even when the set $U$ is not there open and why the function $F$ vanishes near each poit of $\text{Bd}W_i$ not in $L$. Finally I poit out that  I did not study lebesgue integration theory and Munkres book don't use it. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: For quite a lot of things with smooth manifolds, you reduce to the case of a single coordinate patch by using partitions of unity.  They are one  of the reasons that smooth  manifolds are so well behaved compared to some other kinds of manifolds.  They give you ways of reducing integrals on a manifold to integrals on charts (multiply by a partition of unity, your function is a sum of functions that have support in a single chart), they give you that every manifold has a non-degenerate metric on the tangent space (make one on each chart, multiply by partition of unity, add), etc.  Very useful.

Comment: @Aaron Okay. Finally you can say to me why for each $i=1,...,N$ the set $W_i$ is open? It is some days I am resarching an explanation but it seems I do not be able to do it unfortunately. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Intersection of two open sets is open. Inverse image of an open set under a continuous map is open.

Comment: Surely, I know this but unfortunately the set $U$ could be not open in $\Bbb R^k$ -e.g. see figure 25.3- and instead Munkres stated that $W_i$ is there open: so what can you say about?

Comment: Do you have an explanation for this?

Comment: Um....perhaps I understood: the map $\alpha^{-1}_i\circ\alpha$ is a diffeomorphism between $W_i$ and $U_i:=\alpha^{-1}_i[ M_i\cap V]$ and so $U_i:=(\alpha^{-1}_i\circ\alpha)[W_i]$ is open in $A_i$ and so in $\Bbb R^k$ but why this implies that $W_i=(\alpha^{-1}\circ\alpha_i)[U_i]=(\alpha^{-1}_i\circ\alpha)^{-1}[U_i]$ is there open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to see that removing the set $K$ does not affect the integral. (Just use the fact that $f$ is bounded.)

Second, by (finite) additivity of the integral, it suffices to see that the result holds for $M=M_j$. For this, you need to use a (perhaps countably infinite) open cover of $M$ by coordinate charts and a partition of unity $\{\phi_i\}$ subordinate to it. Writing $f=\sum \phi_i f$, we then reduce to the case of *one* function $\phi_i f$ whose support is contained in a single coordinate chart, and Munkres treats this case.

Comment: First of all I thank you for your assistance: you quickly answered to me, so thanks too much.

Comment: However unfortunately I don't understand why I have to prove that the removal (what menas this precisely?) of $K$ does not affect the integral and then it seems I don't see how use the "narrowness" of $f$ to prove it. Then I don't completely understand what you stated in the second part of the answer: so I undestood that you stated that $$\int_M f dV=\int_{M_1} f+....+\int_{M_N} fdV$$ but I don't see form where I can argue this (surely not by theorem 25.3) and then I don't understand how to relate this with you stated to follow.

Comment: Anyway I substantially explained to me as to follow your arguments. So by lemma $25.2$ there exist a partition of unity $\phi_1,...,\phi_l$ such that $\text{support}(\phi_i)\cap M\subseteq V_i$ where $V_i$ is the immage of a coordinate patch so that the support of the function $\phi_i\cdot f$ is contained in $V_i$ too it is trivially covered by a single coordinate patch.

Comment: So if the theorem holds for the function whose support is covered by a single coordinate patch then $$
\int_M(\phi_i f)\,dV=\sum_{j=1}^N\int_{A_j}(\phi_i\circ\alpha_j)F_j
$$
where $F_j:=(f\circ\alpha_j)V(D\alpha_j)$ for each $j=1,...,N$ and so finally summing over $i=1,...,l$ and using theorem $25.3$ and the third point of lemma $25.2$ we have prove the enunciated.

Comment: So is what I say correct? do you want substantially to say this? Excuse me: forgive  my confusion.

Comment: This looks right. Presumably, Munkres argued earlier somewhere that a set of measure zero cannot contribute to the integral. If he did not argue that, it's part of the content of this result. (And it's a good observation to make. For example, you could integrate over the sphere by integrating instead over the upper and lower open hemispheres. Omitting the equator does not affect the integral.).

Comment: Okay. Finally there is another thing I don't understand of the proof. If I edit the question could you explain it to me? It is some days I am researching a solution but unfortunately all solutions I proposed then they reveal themself incorrect. Excuse me for the bother but unfortunately as autodidact I don't know other people that can explain it to me. Thanks for all you explained to me.

Comment: It would be a good idea if you put the entire question there to start with, rather than adding more material from the text after I answered. ... I actually think my proof is more straightforward. Somewhere he still should have argued that a set of measure zero doesn't affect the integral (as he just used that in what you added). Then use coordinate charts supported in the individual $M_i$ to prove the result.

Comment: Yes, Munkres prove in the theorem $11.3$ of the text that the integral of a set of measure zero is zero. Then excuse me if I edited the question: unfortunately I was sure that my explanation about the **overture** of $W_i$ is fine but unfortuately it is not correct when $U$ is not open in $\Bbb R^k$ so I thought to ask to you an explanation, that's all. Excuse me, please.

Comment: You're forgetting the most basic things. The domain of a coordinate chart *is* an open subset of the manifold (perhaps with boundary); its image in $\Bbb R^k$  (perhaps $\Bbb H^k$) *is* open.

Comment: No, I remember this. What I did not understand was why $W_i$ is open in $\Bbb R^k$ when $U$ is **not** open **there** but then I discover (my topology book -Elementos de Topología general by Fidel Casarrubias Segura and Ángel Tamariz Mascarúa- **never** mention it) the invariance domani theorem and then the result is clear since $(α^{-1}_{i}\circ α)$ is a homeomorphism. So is correct my last argjmet to explain the *overture* of $W_i$ when $U$ is not open in $\Bbb R^k$? Forgive my ignorace about the incariabce theorem of domain.

Comment: Here you have smooth maps, so the inverse function theorem does it immediately. Munkres is not dealing with abstract manifolds, surely. Invariance of domain has no place in this treatment.

Comment: That's right!!! I forgot it! Thanks too much for your assistance!!! Excuse me for the bother.